# LMDB: Is there any peformance difference iterating backwards vs forwards?

Tags: c, lmdb

By default LMDB uses lexicographical order for keys in it's B+ tree. This can be overridden by providing a custom comparison function or by modifiying the stored keys so they sort differently.

Is there any performance difference when iterating backwards over the tree, versus forwards? I expect to search always in the descending, backwards direction, so I want to know if that's fine or if I should consider changing the order of how records are inserted.

Comment: Same answer as for all performance questions - measure it.

Comment: 2nd answer to all performance questions - it depends (access pattern, size of data, hardware in particular cache size etc).